# displaying textView instead of a toast message

Tags: android

I have the following instruction displaying some information from the database in `Toast` message, but I want an instruction that display the information but in a `TextView`

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Thank you very much.

This is the declaration of my `TextView`:

```
displayTextViewTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
```

Comment: `displayTextViewTitle.setText("your msg");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
        displayTextViewTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
        displayTextViewTitle.setText(marker.getTitle().toString);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> displayTextViewTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
>   displayTextViewTitle.setText(""+marker.getTitle());

Answer (score 0):

write like below:

```
displayTextViewTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 0):

use `displayTextViewTitle.setText(marker.getTitle())`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

displayTextViewTitle.setText(""+marker.getTitle());

Answer (score 0):

"(..) but I want an instruction that display the information but in a TextView".

Why not read TextView [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) if you want to work with TextView? You just might find a method that can do what you require. The docs is your friend, learn to like it :)